# How to show confirmation message before leaving the screen in react-router-dom V6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I need to add a new feature to my work project, when the user wants to leave the page, a confirmation message should appear that they really want to do.

I found a working example but it is in `react-router-dom@5`. In the project of the company I work for, they use `react-router-dom@6`. I tried to adapt it but it didn't work, mainly because of the `block()` method.

Here's my adapted code I put into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-wing-769q2z?file=/src/components/TestingPage.js)

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import ExitDialog from "./ExitDialog";

const TestingPage = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [isVisibleDialog, setVisibleDialog] = useState(false);
  const [triggerExit, setTriggerExit] = useState({
    onOk: false,
    path: ""
  });

  const handleGoToIntendedPage = useCallback(
    (location) => navigate(location),
    [navigate]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (triggerExit.onOk) {
      handleGoToIntendedPage(triggerExit.path);
    }

    const unblock = navigate.block((location) => {
      if (location.pathname !== "/testing") {
        setVisibleDialog(true);
      }
      setTriggerExit((obj) => ({ ...obj, path: location.pathname }));
      if (triggerExit.onOk) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });

    return () => {
      unblock();
    };
  }, [handleGoToIntendedPage, navigate, triggerExit.onOk, triggerExit.path]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>You are currently in Testing Page</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </div>
      <ExitDialog
        visible={isVisibleDialog}
        onClose={() => setVisibleDialog(false)}
        onOk={() => {
          setTriggerExit((obj) => ({
            ...obj,
            onOk: true
          }));
          setVisibleDialog(false);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestingPage;
```

This is the example that is working with [`react-router-dom@5`](https://codesandbox.io/s/navigation-change-with-react-router-forked-m7tmn5?file=/src/components/TestingPage.js)

[image]

Can you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: What ***specific*** version of `react-router-dom@6` is your app using? RRDv6 has had quite a few changes during its life. See if you can use the official [navigation-blocking](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/tree/dev/examples/navigation-blocking) demo.

Comment: Hii Drew, I'm using react-router: 6.9.0 and react-router-dom: 6.10.0

Comment: I saw that in your sandbox, but I just wanted to confirm what your company's codebase is using. You don't need both `react-router` and `react-router-dom` (*RRD re-exports **all** of RR*), but you certainly don't want different versions of each at the same time. Are you needing to use the regular router or is your app using the newer Data routers? I *believe* the blocking APIs work only with the Data routers. Depending on how you are organizing your routes it's likely a trivial task to convert to a Data router and follow the demo I linked in my previous comment.

Comment: Hii Drew, sorry now I understand, here the version we're using in my job: react-router-dom: ^6.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, in the `react-router-dom@6.9.0` version used in the sandbox you linked the following method still works.

1. Create and use a `HistoryRouter` router and custom `history` object. This requires the `history` package as a project dependency.

   1. Add `history` as a project dependency: `npm install --save history@5`.
   2. Create the custom history object.

      /src/history.js

      ```
      import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

      export default createBrowserHistory();
      ```
   3. Import the `HistoryRouter` and your custom `history` object, instantiate the router.

      ```
      import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
      import {
        unstable_HistoryRouter as Router // <-- HistoryRouter
      } from "react-router-dom";
      import history from './history';   // <-- custom history object
      import App from "./App";

      const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
      const root = createRoot(rootElement);

      root.render(
        <Router history={history}> // <-- render HistoryRouter
          <App />
        </Router>
      );
      ```
2. Update `TestingPage` to import and use the custom `history` object. Note that `history.block` callback takes a single argument where `location` is just one of the properties.

   ```
   import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
   import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
   import ExitDialog from "./ExitDialog";
   import history from '../history';

   const TestingPage = () => {
     const navigate = useNavigate();

     const [isVisibleDialog, setVisibleDialog] = useState(false);
     const [triggerExit, setTriggerExit] = useState({
       onOk: false,
       path: ""
     });

     const handleGoToIntendedPage = useCallback((location) => navigate(location), [
       navigate
     ]);

     useEffect(() => {
       if (triggerExit.onOk) {
         handleGoToIntendedPage(triggerExit.path);
       }

       const unblock = history.block(({ location }) => { // <-- block callback
         if (location.pathname !== "/testing") {
           setVisibleDialog(true);
         }
         setTriggerExit((obj) => ({ ...obj, path: location.pathname }));
         if (triggerExit.onOk) {
           return true;
         }
         return false;
       });

       return () => {
         unblock();
       };
     }, [handleGoToIntendedPage, navigate, triggerExit.onOk, triggerExit.path]);

     return (
       <div>
         <div>
           <h1>You are currently in Testing Page</h1>
         </div>
         <ExitDialog
           visible={isVisibleDialog}
           onClose={() => setVisibleDialog(false)}
           onOk={() => {
             setTriggerExit((obj) => ({
               ...obj,
               onOk: true
             }));
             setVisibleDialog(false);
           }}
         />
       </div>
     );
   };

   export default TestingPage;
   ```

[image: Edit how-to-show-confirmation-message-before-leaving-the-screen-in-react-router-dom-v]

The `HistoryRouter` is renamed (*and marked "unstable"*) which means it could be removed at any time, but it's been included with each minor release including the current stable release (*v6.15.0 as of this posting*).

[HistoryRouter Source](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L449-L492)